# Circular variance of a mixture of Von Mises distributions

Tags: variance, simulation, circular-statistics, analytical, von-mises-distribution

Does anyone know if there is an analytical solution for the (circular) variance of a mixture of Von Mises distributions that all have equal (circular) mean?

Simulation results suggest that the circular variance of such a mixture is equal to the average of the circular variances of the individual components, at least when the mixture weights are the same.

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to a mathematical proof or rejection. Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Doesn't this follow directly from the linearity of [the integrals involved in the definition of the circular variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics)? The absolute values might throw things off, though...